# Personalizar meu modal bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal funcionando:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"      aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"    UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Quero mexer no `body`. Quero que tenha 4 botões abaixo do outro, e colocar um texto ao lado, sendo que tudo que coloco lá vai para baixo um do outro, como colocar algo do lado? E como colocar uma barra de rolagem? Pois estou preparando o mesmo para uma lista de dados.

Comment: Este `aria-  hidden="true"` é proposital com estes dois espaços no meio?

Comment: na verdade isso é so uma propriedade do botão, nao importa o componente, se eu colocar um label, ou button do asp.net sempre vai pra baixo um do outro, quero saber como colocar um do lado.

Comment: Basta usar `display:inline-block` nesses botões internos.

Comment: coloco isso aonde?

Comment: @renan como faço??

Comment: @WarLock tentou usar as classes, col-sm, col-lg, col-xs? EX: `<div class="col-sm-6">Conteúdo Um</div><div class="col-sm-6">Conteúdo ao lado</div>`

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte:

- Utilize `float: left` para fazer o menu ir para a esquerda.
- Faça os botões ficarem com `display: block` e coloque-os dentro do menu, assim vão aparecer um debaixo do outro.
- Crie um contêiner para o texto, que ficara após o menu no HTML, e coloque nesse contêiner o estilo `overflow: hidden`. Isso fará com que seu texto não interaja com o menu floated.
- resultado

  [image: Resultado]

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
}
.menu > button {
  display: block;
}
.conteudo {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal();
    });
  });
</script>
<button id="btn">Mostrar modal</button>


<!-- Bootstrap Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
              <div class="menu">
                <button>Botão 1</button>
                <button>Botão 2</button>
                <button>Botão 3</button>
              </div>
              <div class="conteudo">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec felis neque, maximus in justo eu, dictum semper augue. Etiam viverra mollis dui facilisis iaculis. Nullam rutrum lectus eget dolor blandit accumsan. Vestibulum accumsan ligula tortor, at facilisis
                neque bibendum et.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```